# Absolute reference to node in DOMDocument for use later?

Tags: php

I'm traversing an XML file and displaying certain attributes and node values in an HTML form. After the form is submitted, I'd like to insert the values of form fields into the XML file directly.

Basically, I'm building an "online xml editor" for specific nodes and attributes.

I'm using DOMDocument to load the XML, I find all the attributes & node values that I want to change. What I need now is to save unique identifiers for each edited node so that after posting I can save form fields into XML.

I can store XPATH into an array like this

```
array_push($edited_images, $image->getNodePath());
```

... but I don't know how to access these nodes on the next page. I would need some kind of method to do this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
...
$node_to_edit = $doc->selectOneNodeBySpecificXPATH($edited_images[0]);
$node_to_edit->->setAttribute($a, 'FORM FIELD CONTENT FROM PAGE');
```

I can't find a method that would help me to select a single node using XPATH though. Is there a better unique identifier for a node for DOMDocument? Or a better general approach for what I need?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: You use xpath then with the `DomXpath` object. If you need unique identifiers, you will need to have IDs, XML offers that. Specify in your DTD what the ID is and then `getElementByID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select a single node using XPath, use [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php):

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$node = $xpath->query($edited_images[0])->item(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

To select a single node using the stored XPath, use [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/class.domxpath) and it's `query` function:

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$node = $xpath->query($edited_images[0]);
$node && $node = $node->item(0);
```

As it returns a [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/DOMNodeList), you need to select the first one if successful. If `$node` still evaluates `false` do the error handling.

The other thing is to use IDs, but it looks like that you don't have any.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. What is this "node && node" thing? Shortcut for checking something?